# Add value of button into input field on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I am new to JavaScript. I want to make a calculator, but I am stuck on getting button value into field. Suppose I have following button

```
<input id='add' type='button' onclick='ik();'  value='1'>
```

and following field

```
<input type='text' id='one' class='fld'>
```

Hope I'll get clear with you replies...

Comment: thanks @AnthonyForloney

Comment: Google it. You will find solution.

Comment: check out my updated code

Answer (score 7):

You can customize it in anyway you want.

```js
function ik(val){
document.getElementById('one').value = val;  
}
```

```html
<input id='add' type='button' onclick='ik(this.value);'  value='1'>
<input type='text' id='one' class='fld'>
```

And, if you want to add to the current value:

```js
function ik(val){
   result = document.getElementById('one');
   result.value = result.value? parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(val) : parseInt(val);  
}
```

```html
<input id='add' type='button' onclick='ik(this.value);'  value='1'>
<input type='text' id='one' class='fld'>
```

Answer (score 1):

While i can't see your code for some reason, if you included any in your post, here would be one way to achieve what you are describing:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#your-input-id")
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.number-button")


for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    input.value = input.value + event.currentTarget.value
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="your-input-id" type="text" value="" />
<button class="number-button" value="2">2</button>
<button class="number-button" value="3">3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick =)

```
$(function () {
  $("#add").on("click", function () {
    $("#one").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply just do this.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#one").val($(this).val());
});
```

You can also see it work here.
https://jsfiddle.net/8uc66vsp/

Answer (score -1):

### Try This

```
<input type='text' id='one' class='fld'>
<input id='add' type='button' onclick='ik($(this).val());'  value='1'>

<script>
function ik(str){
 $("#one").val(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sloppy - no / in closing script tag and using .value on $() instead of .val()